# if $ L = \lim_{x\to1^-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = L$

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

let ${a_n}$ be a sequence of Real non negative numbers.

assume the following limit exists and is finite:

$$ L = \lim_{x\to1^-} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$$

prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges to L

note: by $\lim_{x\to1^-}$ I mean that the limit is that x goes to 1 but $x < 1$.

Comment: I'd say you do it in two steps. a) Show that the limit exists b) show that it must equal L. I'd say most of the work is in a)

Comment: Is it assumed that the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ is $1$ or more?

Comment: @ColmBhandal I guess you are right, the main part is a, and nothing is given about the radius of convergence, (of course if its bigger then 1 the the you get the answer).

Comment: Here is a conjecture: Assuming the first limit exists (as it does), you should be able to show that $a_n$ eventually always goes below any  given value $\epsilon$. Otherwise, you can make $x$ close enough to $1$ and get an arbitrarily large term...

Comment: @ajotatxe : Do you see it in the assumptions? :P

Comment: A (very) simple proof can be obtained by using monotone convergence theorem with respect to the counting measure. But if you do not know measure theory, this will not be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in the *title* is false. But it's true under the additional assumption that $a_n\ge0$. And it's actually quite easy.

Since $a_n\ge0$ there exists $S\in[0,\infty]$ such that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=S.$$(Note we allowed the possibility $S=\infty$.) Now for a given $N$,
$$\sum_{n=0}^Na_n=\lim_{x\to1}\sum_{n=0}^N a_nx^n\le L.$$So $$S=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N a_n\le L.$$

For the other direction, say $\epsilon>0$. There exists $x\in(0,1)$ with $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n>L-\epsilon.$$But $$S\ge\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n.$$So $S>L-\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, hence $S\ge L$.

Comment: How can you can conclude $S=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^N a_n\le L.$ doesnt the sum need to uniformly converge in the interval [0,1] for that?

Comment: Not sure whether you're asking about (i) $S=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^n a_n$ or (ii) $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^n a_n\le L$. Of course (i) is just a definition. For (ii): Look at what I proved just above that! I gave a proof that $\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\le L$. If those partial sums are all no larger than $L$ then their limit is no larger than $L$. (In fact the sum _does_ converge uniformly on $[0,1]$, but I didn't use that so I don't have to prove it.)